# i just want to import spacy but i get the msgpack error

Tags: python

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-76a01d9c502b> in <module>
----> 1 import spacy

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>
      8 from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
      9 
---> 10 from .cli.info import info as cli_info
     11 from .glossary import explain
     12 from .about import __version__

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .download import download
      2 from .info import info
      3 from .link import link
      4 from .package import package
      5 from .profile import profile

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from ._messages import Messages
---> 11 from .link import link
     12 from ..util import prints, get_package_path
     13 from .. import about

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\link.py in <module>
      7 from ._messages import Messages
      8 from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
----> 9 from ..util import prints
     10 from .. import util
     11 

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in <module>
     25 # Import these directly from Thinc, so that we're sure we always have the
     26 # same version.
---> 27 from thinc.neural._classes.model import msgpack
     28 from thinc.neural._classes.model import msgpack_numpy
     29 

ImportError: cannot import name 'msgpack' from 'thinc.neural._classes.model' (C:\Users\salwa\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\_classes\model.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with thinc, a dependency of spaCy, as you can see here: `ImportError: cannot import name 'msgpack' from 'thinc.neural._classes.model'`

Follow Ines's (a core developer of spaCy) suggestion that you can find [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3854),

> It looks like you might have ended up with conflicting installationds
>   and dependencies – for example, the latest version of spaCy, but an
>   older version of its dependency, Thinc. In cases like this, it often
>   helps to just start out with a clean environment and reinstall from
>   scratch.